# Too many php cookies

Tags: php, cookies

Will having too many php cookies on a webpage slow it down a significant amount? On a site I've created I'm considering adding a feature, which would be nice, but require quite a few php cookies to be stored. Will this make the site slower?

Comment: You are probably looking for user authentication and session management.

Answer (score 2):

It won't, but there is limit for cookie length. Save only necessary informations (security token) and take it from your server instead

Comment: Well what I want to do is add a feature similar to the facebook like button, but in order to keep people from clicking it more than once, I'd have to store a cookie every time someone clicks it. Would this be a problem?

Comment: @Max: yes. never trust user's input. save it on server

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Cookies are transmitted to the server for each http request your browser does.

If you have a few number of cookies, you won't see any difference.